# mongoose format date when return data

Tags: mongoose

I use `myModel.find();`

Results:

```
 {
    _id : "5afe3beb6fb6b70bfffaff13",
    name: "test01",
    birthday:   "Mon Jun 04 2018 14:56:46 GMT+0700 (+07)",           
},
{
    _id : "5afe3beb6fb6b70bfffafrr13",
    name: "test02",
    birthday:  "Mon Jun 04 2018 14:56:46 GMT+0700 (+07)",       
},
```

How to **convert** "birthday" field from **ISODate** to **(Y-m-d)** ?
*Note:Don't update database*

Results wish:

```
  {
    _id : "5afe3beb6fb6b70bfffaff13",
    name: "test02",
    birthday:  "2018-06-06",       
},
{
    _id : "5afe3beb6fb6b70bfffafrr13",
    name: "test02",
    birthday:  "2018-06-06",   

},
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Hey @NeilLunn ! I'm did edit question. Can you reviews it again ?

Comment: You have the wrong operator and I think you mean [`$dateFromString`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateFromString/), but it won't just convert "any" format. And it does not think your "strings" are valid. Marked to the different duplicates of this question. Please don't change the question again.

Comment: Sorry mate! .Your  answer not right  my request.I search but not result. I need result like same on mongodb [link here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/)